# Arquillian Cube with Algeron

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, pact

I am successfully running Arquillian Cube tests, but as soon as arquillian-algeron-pact-consumer-core and pact-jvm-consumer_2.12 are just on the classpath, not even used in the tests, all tests are not executed but green, so errors are never detected. The test methods are also written in the junit report.

Is this behaviour just reasonable or is it a bug?

Example (I am running a wildfly-swarm in the container, so no deployment section):

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class CubeTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertEquals(1, 2);
    }
}
```

Used Versions are:

```
arquillian: 1.1.14.Final  
cube: 1.9.2 
algeron: 2.0.0-rc.2 (also for 1.0.1)
pact-jvm-consumer_2.12: 3.5.1 (also for 3.4.1)
```

Comment: Have you tried using a real Algeron project I mean, adding Algeron as dependency and use the required annotations as well. Although of course this seems a bug, probably the issue is that you are setting that a test wants to be a contract test but you are not adding anything related with it.

Comment: Can you provide a project for that so we can debug? Thanks.

Comment: Please find an example at https://github.com/michaeljank/cube-algeron/, as soon as you comment out the dependencies to algeron/pact the test fails as expected